# TimeStamp coming in as null while using AWS Glue to load db table

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, aws-glue

I'm pulling some data from a csv file and ingesting that data into a staging table using `AWS-Glue`. That being said, I've noticed that when writing to the staging table timestamps are coming in as null. At first I thought that the data was sending null values in the `order_date` field, but then I noticed the data wasn't null, but when converting from `string` to `timestamp` this tends to happen. I was initially going to use pandas and call a function but there's about 300 million rows on average so it wouldn't be wise to use pandas, and I'm not sure if that would yield the same result with the ingestion. Along with that, the client prefers that we don't update the crawler for this ETL process.

Any assistance with this is greatly appreciated!

My code looks like:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)


# Universal Paramters
quotes = '"'
dedicated_file_path = "my_s3_bucket"

original_data = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    format_options={"quoteChar": quotes, 'withHeader':True, "separator": '|'}
    , connection_type='s3'
    , format='csv'
    , connection_options={
        'paths': [dedicated_file_path]
        , 'recurse': True
    }
    , transformation_ctx = "original_data"
)

# Transforming to spark dataframe for handling timestamp
modified_df = original_data.toDf().withColumn("order_date"
                                , to_timestamp(col("order_date"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))

# Back to dynamic_frame
updated_schema = Dynamic_frame.fromDF(dataFrame, glueContext, "modified_df")

dy_df = ApplyMapping.apply(frame=updated_schema
                           , mappings=[("order_date", "timestamp", "order_date", 'timestamp')]
                           , transformation_ctx='dy_df')

update_stg_tbl = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    frame=dy_df
    , database="dev_proc"
    , table_name="dev_device_stg"
    , transformation_ctx="update_stg_tbl"
)


job.commit()
```

Error looks like:

```
Error: null value in column 'order_date' of relation "dev_device_stg" violates not-null contraint.
```

DF data looks like:

```
+--------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------+
|order_id|         order_date|order_customer_id|   order_status|
+--------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------+
|       1|2013-07-25 00:00:00|            11599|         CLOSED|
|       2|2013-07-25 00:00:00|              256|PENDING_PAYMENT|
|       3|2013-07-25 00:00:00|            12111|       COMPLETE|
|       4|2013-07-25 00:00:00|             8827|         CLOSED|
|       5|2013-07-25 00:00:00|            11318|       COMPLETE|
|       6|2013-07-25 00:00:00|             7130|       COMPLETE|
|       7|2013-07-25 00:00:00|             4530|       COMPLETE|
|       8|2013-07-25 00:00:00|             2911|     PROCESSING|
|       9|2013-07-25 00:00:00|             5657|PENDING_PAYMENT|
|      10|2013-07-25 00:00:00|             5648|PENDING_PAYMENT|
|      11|2013-07-25 00:00:00|              918| PAYMENT_REVIEW|
|      12|2013-07-25 00:00:00|             1837|         CLOSED|
|      13|2013-07-25 00:00:00|             9149|PENDING_PAYMENT|
|      14|2013-07-25 00:00:00|             9842|     PROCESSING|
|      15|2013-07-25 00:00:00|             2568|       COMPLETE|
|      16|2013-07-25 00:00:00|             7276|PENDING_PAYMENT|
|      17|2013-07-25 00:00:00|             2667|       COMPLETE|
|      18|2013-07-25 00:00:00|             1205|         CLOSED|
|      19|2013-07-25 00:00:00|             9488|PENDING_PAYMENT|
|      20|2013-07-25 00:00:00|             9198|     PROCESSING|
+--------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------+
```